# Linking to specifik posts from facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I show posts that i've downloaded using facebook graph api. I want to be able to link to the posts where I display them.

Facebook provides those links via the stream api:s actions. They like this:
http://www.facebook.com/284328420994/posts/10150830378060995

Theese links work for comments on pages, but not comments on groups. Those comments render a 404.

Why is this and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an URL in the form of

```
https://www.facebook.com/groups/{group id}/permalink/{post id}/
```

– that should work, if the post is publicly available. (Otherwise it’ll work only for group members who are allowed to see it.)

Comment: Brilliant! Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I don’t know, I just clicked on the “x minutes ago”-link in one of my group postings ;-)